# Go to last session's last edit

Tags: evil

In vim, right after opening a file, I can type `g;` to go to
the place last edited.  This doesn't work in evil-mode with my
configuration.  Is there something I can do to make it work?

Comment: This looks like a limitation in the package used to provide `g;`, goto-chg.

Comment: you'd have to save your session info with `desktop` before you quit and maybe then you can use `goto-chg` to view the last edit place in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your init file:

```
(require 'saveplace)
(setq-default save-place t)
```

From `saveplace.el`:

```
;; Automatically save place in files, so that visiting them later
;; (even during a different Emacs session) automatically moves point
;; to the saved position, when the file is first found.  Uses the
;; value of buffer-local variable save-place to determine whether to
;; save position or not.
```

Comment: Thanks! I put in `(save-place-mode 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I also use `saveplace`, however it actually doesn't save the point of the last edit, but the point that was last visited before closing a file.

If you want to save the last edited point, you can combine `saveplace` and `goto-last-change`. You have to install the package `goto-last-change`.

You have to define a function, that returns the last point saved from `goto-last-change`.

```
(defun my-last-edited-point ()
  "Return point of last edit in file."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-last-change)    
    (point)))
```

Then you have to replace `point` in `save-place-to-alist` with `my-last-edited-point`. I just paste the modified function so you don't have to look for it yourself.

```
(defun save-place-to-alist ()
  ;; put filename and point in a cons box and then cons that onto the
  ;; front of the save-place-alist, if save-place is non-nil.
  ;; Otherwise, just delete that file from the alist.
  ;; first check to make sure alist has been loaded in from the master
  ;; file.  If not, do so, then feel free to modify the alist.  It
  ;; will be saved again when Emacs is killed.
  (or save-place-loaded (load-save-place-alist-from-file))
  (let ((item (or buffer-file-name
                  (and (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
               dired-directory
               (expand-file-name (if (consp dired-directory)
                         (car dired-directory)
                       dired-directory))))))
    (when (and item
               (or (not save-place-ignore-files-regexp)
                   (not (string-match save-place-ignore-files-regexp
                                      item))))
      (let ((cell (assoc item save-place-alist))
            (position (cond ((eq major-mode 'hexl-mode)
                 (with-no-warnings
                   (1+ (hexl-current-address))))
                ((and (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
                  dired-directory)
                 (let ((filename (dired-get-filename nil t)))
                   (if filename
                   `((dired-filename . ,filename))
                 (my-last-edited-point))))
                (t (my-last-edited-point)))))
        (if cell
            (setq save-place-alist (delq cell save-place-alist)))
        (if (and save-place
                 (not (and (integerp position)
               (= position 1)))) ;; Optimize out the degenerate case.
            (setq save-place-alist
                  (cons (cons item position)
                        save-place-alist)))))))
```